# How to factor $ x^3 − 2ax −a $

Tags: factoring

I have:

$$
x^3 -2k^2x - k^2 = 0
$$

Now, I want to factor it so that I can easily solve for $x$, as you can see I cannot directy use quadratic formula. AFAIK, I am expecting 3 terms here like $(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)=0$. Thanks in advance and more power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is in the form of a monic depressed cubic (leading coefficient=1 and no quadratic term), Cardano's method is a good way to go to find the solutions. Unfortunately, for arbitrary $k,$ [the solutions aren't pretty](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3-2%2ak%5E2%2ax%3Dk%5E2&x=0&y=0), so the factorization is not going to be easily done.

Answer (score 1):

You should check on [cubic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function). Yours is the special case of a depressed cubic, the details of the solution method are given in the linked Wikipedia entry. My tame computer algebra system [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) gives the three roots, they are a veritable mess.